# Jquery Autocomplete error after load php in div : Uncaught "TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined "

Tags: php, jquery

My auto-complete getting error after loading php from selected item.

I want to create autocomplete and then load php file based on the selection, but after page is loaded, and typed some string again, got some result but. even just hover it  it or select the item it gives error, shown from my chrome console. 
I also tried change _renderItemData to _renderItem , but no difference.

```
$('#mainsearch').autocomplete({          
                minLength: 0,
                source: studentArray,
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                        $( "#mainsearch" ).val( ui.item.label );
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        $( "#mainsearch" ).val( ui.item.label );        
                        $( "#mainsearch-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                        $( "#mainsearch-description" ).html( ui.item.label );                           
                        $( "#mainsearch-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );
                        showitem(ui.item.label);

                        return false;
                    }
                  }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItemData = function( ul, item ) {
                      return $( "<li>" )
                        .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
                        .append( "MY CUSTOM STYLE" )
                        .appendTo(ul);
                    }; // END OF AUTOCOMPLETE
```

and my load page code:

```
function showitem(selectedentity){
                    $("#resultbox").html(" <div id='closeresult' name='closeresult' >X </div>" +
                    "<div ><h1>"+
                    selectedentity+
                    "</h1></div> ");

             $("#resultbox").load('browseFrame.php');

            }; // END OF showitem().
```

The errors :

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined search2.php:124 
$.autocomplete.focus search2.php:124
$.Widget._trigger 12437:785
_on.menufocus 12437:6849
handlerProxy 12437:702
jQuery.event.dispatch 12436:3074
elemData.handle 12436:2750
jQuery.event.trigger 12436:2986
(anonymous function) 12436:3677
jQuery.extend.each 12436:648
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each 12436:270
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger 12436:3676
$.Widget._trigger 12437:783
$.widget.focus 12437:11795
(anonymous function) 12437:401
_on.mouseenter .ui-menu-item 12437:11505
handlerProxy 12437:702
jQuery.event.special.(anonymous function).handle 12436:3431
jQuery.event.dispatch  36:3074
elemData.handle
```

**UPDATE :** 
Tried remove ALL javascript declaration as below from my loaded php file and everthing just fine :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>   
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Can't explain why, but now my autocomplete works good and no more errors.

Sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

JQuery(or any JS lib) needs to be loaded before you use can use it otherwise it will be threated as without jQuery... Load jQuery/jQuery UI in the head instead and you will be fine.